# Formatting Issue with Timeline Display in Microsoft Lists

Tags: json, sharepoint-list

I need help with the following code. I have a list in Microsoft Lists, and this code is responsible for turning it into a timeline. Everything was working fine until I converted the text in the 'Description' column into 'Enhanced rich text,' and now all that appears is HTML code.
Can someone help me resolve this? I've been researching, and I saw suggestions to use '@currentfield,' but it's not working.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "block",
      "width": "100%",
      "padding": "50px 0",
      "position": "relative",
      "overflow": "hidden"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralQuaternary"
        },
        "style": {
          "position": "absolute",
          "top": "0",
          "left": "50%",
          "margin-left": "-1px",
          "width": "2px",
          "height": "100%",
          "z-index": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "width": "50%",
          "justify-content": "space-between",
          "float": "=if(@rowIndex % 2 == 0, 'left', 'right')",
          "flex-direction": "=if(@rowIndex % 2 == 0, 'row-reverse', 'row')",
          "margin": "=if(@rowIndex % 2 == 0, '0 0 0 8px', '0 8px 0 0')"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-borderColor-themeLighterAlt"
            },
            "style": {
              "box-sizing": "border-box",
              "width": "16px",
              "height": "16px",
              "border-radius": "50%",
              "border-width": "2px",
              "border-style": "solid",
              "margin-top": "10px",
              "z-index": "9999"
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "box-sizing": "border-box",
              "width": "95%",
              "padding": "0 15px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-32 ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
                },
                "style": {
                  "margin": "5px 0",
                  "font-weight": "700",
                  "text-align": "=if(@rowIndex % 2 == 0, 'right', 'left')"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-14"
                },
                "style": {
                  "line-height": "1.6em",
                  "word-spacing": "1px",
                  "font-weight": "600",
                  "text-align": "=if(@rowIndex % 2 == 0, 'right', 'left')"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Description]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried converting the text in the 'Description' column into 'Enhanced rich text' in Microsoft Lists. I expected the text to display correctly within the timeline, but instead, it's showing HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Line Text columns with enhanced rich text in SharePoint online lists or Microsoft lists does not support SharePoint JSON column formatting.

Also, when you refer these columns in the JSON formatting either using `@currentField` or using their [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/), it shows the HTML code which is stored in that column value.

This is a limitation of SharePoint JSON formatting and unfortunately, there is no workaround for this using JSON formatting.

You will have to use the Multi-Line Text columns with plain text in your lists.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting - Supported column types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)